# How to delete all entries from a table which have exceeded an expiration limit in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am using **PostgreSQL** and **Sequelize ORM**. I have a Token table in the DB that stores the token for email verification of a new user. I want to set the tokens in such a way that the tokens expire after a fixed interval of time, meaning, the tokens that have a creation timestamp which was, for example 1 day ago, should be deleted from the table.

I searched up on google and one of the suggestions was to use a trigger and on every insert of an entry the trigger calls a stored procedure to remove all entries according to the above mentioned criteria. But this method has loopholes for my use case.

The following code is the user.js model file that I am currently using

```js
'use strict';
const _ = require("lodash");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    verified: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {});

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Code);
    User.hasOne(models.Token);
  }

  User.authenticate = async function(email, password) {
    const user = await User.findOne({where: { email }});
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("Email not registered");
    }

    const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!result) {
      throw new Error("Password is incorrect");
    }

    return user.authorize();
  }

  User.prototype.authorize = async function() {
      const user = _.pick(this.toJSON(), ["id", "email", "name", "role"]);
      const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 1440
      });

      return { user, token};
  };
  return User;
};
```

Comment: If you set expiresIn, token expiration is handled by jsonwebtoken.  `jwt.verify` will return TokenExpiredError when it is expired.

Comment: Actually I'm setting the token to a randomly generated hash. This token is not a JWT. I just need to delete the entries that were created 24 hours before the current time.

Comment: I see and you are right about the loopholes if no data is inserted in a 24h frame, the trigger won't happen so this is undesirable.  However, if you care unauthorizing and expiring the token over deleting at strict timing, you can verify if token is older than 24h or not at any login and return unauthorized to the user and delete token whenever you find token is older than that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)** for this :

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
console.log('Before job instantiation');
const job = new CronJob('0 1 * * * *', function() {
    const d = new Date();
  console.log(d);
  // write the code for delete 
});
console.log('After job instantiation');
job.start();
```

**[MORE EXAMPLE](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/tree/master/examples)**

Comment: Where should I place this Script on the backend code? Or do I need to run this as a separate script?

Comment: You can put this in your index/server js file or create a separate file and import it in index/server , that will do the job.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot. Will try and get back with the results.